# OctoberCMS: How to extend System\Models\File and add a new field to it?

Tags: php, octobercms, octobercms-plugins

I need to add an extra column to the `system_files` table. I'd prefer not to change this table, so I decided to add a new table with one column and then extend the `System\Models\File` model with a `hasOne` relationship. I therefore created a new table called `myname_plugin_tag` with two fields: `file_id` and `title` and created a new model file for it called `Tag`:

```
class Tag extends Model
{
    use \October\Rain\Database\Traits\Validation;

    /*
     * Validation
     */
    public $rules = [
    ];

    /*
     * Disable timestamps by default.
     * Remove this line if timestamps are defined in the database table.
     */
    public $timestamps = false;

    /**
     * @var string The database table used by the model.
     */
    public $table = 'myname_plugin_tag';
}
```

And in the `boot` method of my plugin I have:

```
System\Models\File::extend(function($model){
    $model->hasOne['tag']=[
        'MyName\Plugin\Models\Tag',
        'key' => 'file_id',
        'timestamps' => 'false'
    ];
});
```

That seems to be all I have to do. But when saving a file with the new relationship I've defined, I get an error.

```
$user = Auth::getUser();

$tag = new Tag;
$tag->title = 'some tag';

$file = new File;
$file->data = Input::file('catalog');
$file->title = Input::get('title');
$file->tag = $tag; // => This line is the culprit. If I comment it, the exception will not raise

$user->files = $file;
$user->save();
```

Exception:

> Call to undefined method October\Rain\Database\QueryBuilder::withTimestamps()
>   E:\Development\git\catalog-manager\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder.php line 2123

If I remove the line `'timestamps' => 'false'`, the exception gets fixed and `$file` model will be saved, but `$tag` model is not saved yet.

Using `$file->tag()->save($tag)` works and saves the tag! But the problem is not solved. I cannot access the saved property via $user->files[0]->tag and get this error:

> Trying to get property of non-object

The output of `{{dump($user->files[0])}}` clearly shows that `tag` property has not been added to the `File` model:

```
id  integer
disk_name  string
file_name  string
file_size  integer
content_type  string
title  string
description  NULL
field  string
sort_order  integer
created_at  string
updated_at  string
path  string
extension  string
```

So it seems that the `File` model is not aware of the new `tag` property added to it. Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: Did you try to remove `'timestamps' => 'false' `?

Comment: @OlegSamorai I removed it and the exception was fixed. But now nothing is saved into the `myname_plugin_tag` table. Only the `file` model is saved.

Comment: Have you added belongsTo relation to MyName\Plugin\Models\Tag ?

Comment: @OlegSamorai I think the reverse of the relation is required only if we want to access the `file` of a `Tag` model. By the way, I added the `belongsTo` relation the `Tag` model but still `Tag` is not being saved.

Comment: Does any code executed into your plugin boot() function?

Comment: @OlegSamorai Yes I've already extended other models and controllers in the same `boot` method and I am sure that the code is executed.

Comment: I cannot try it out, so I'm just guessing:

have you tried using the `add()`method for setting the relationship?

Another thing to try is to first save the file, then the tag, then save the relationship and then add the file to the user.

Comment: @dragontree Please see the updated question. I managed to save the tag using `$file->tag()->save($tag)` but the `$file->tag` relation does not seem to exist yet. What do you mean by "using `add()` method for setting the relationship"? Where should I use it?

Comment: Like this (not sure if it works with hasOne):
`$file->tag()->add($tag);`

Comment: @dragontree Well, I managed to use `$file->tag()->save($tag);`, but still cannot read the `tag` property. Please read the updated question.